# C++: Can one thread see a newly allocated object as uninitialized if passed through boost lockfree queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, lock-free, condition-variable, happens-before

I'm building a multiple-producer single-consumer mechanism.
I want to do something like this, suppose I have access to an instance of boost lockfree queue available for both threads and a synchronizing condition variable:

Thread 1 (producer):

```
Object * myObj = new Object();
lockfree_queue.push(myObj);
condition_variable.notify();
```

Thread 2 (consumer):

```
condition_variable.wait();
Object * myObj = lockfree_queue.pop();
...
delete myObj;
```

Is there a chance that on a multi-core system Thread 2 shall see myObj as pointing to memory that is uninitialized or to object that is partially initialized (suppose it has some member variables)?

Comment: Cv has nothing to do with lock-free. You need to learn about those tools and concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once `new` returns and gives you a pointer, the object is fully constructed.

If there's uninitialized members in the object, then it's the fault of the constructor for not initializing them.

And it shouldn't be a problem even if the queue contained object instances instead of pointers, as the `push` call would be fully done before you notify the condition variable, so the other thread will not even pop the queue until the object is pushed.

Comment: Is this since lockfree_queue.push() is similar to Atomic.store(xxx, memory_order_release) and lockfree_queue.pop() to Atomic.load(memory_order_acquire)?

Comment: @Kikosha No it's because C++ is (in the absence of loops) strictly sequential and you having proper synchronization. In the first thread, the allocation and construction of the object will always happen before you push it to the queue, and the pushing to the queue will always happen (and be completely finished) before you call `condition_variable.notify()`. The second thread will wait on the condition variable, and not continue until the first thread sends the notification.

Comment: What does "strictly sequential" mean?

Comment: @curiousguy Statements are, in the absence of loops or `goto`, executed top to bottom, left to right. In a sequential fashion.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The order of computation of the operands of operators (except `&&`, `||`, `,` and `?:`) is not specified. The order of computation of the elements of a member-init-list in a ctor is the order of declaration.

Comment: @curiousguy Note that I said *statements*.